# unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting ',' or ';'

Tags: php

As I try to load a website the following error shows up:

> unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting ',' or ';'

It says that the error is on line 5.

```
<?php

 ob_start();
 header("Location: /localhost/site1");
 echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='/localhost/site1'">'; //line 5
 die();

?>
```

---

Update:

At this point my code looks like:

```
<?php

 ob_start();
 header("Location: /localhost/site1");
 echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=\'/localhost/site1\'">';
 die();

?>
```

But still the same error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in /localhost/site1/index.php on line 5

I also tried to use:

```
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=/localhost/site1">';
```

But same problem.

Comment: This site is not an interactive debugger. The error message is clear, google is easy to use, and as if that weren't enough: syntax highlighting tells the whole story

Comment: Just remove the `<meta>` tag altogether - it's completely pointless.

Answer (score 3):

Check the quotationmarks...

```
 echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=/localhost/site1">'; //line 5
```

The syntax highlighting of SO shows it:

```
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='/localhost/site1'">'; //line 5
     ^-----                                     ^----------------^  ^- --
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=\'/localhost/site1\'">';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also  `refresh` page from `header` function, try this

```
header("refresh:0; url=/localhost/site1");
```

`meta` tag also do same thing, but your code process is looking incorrect you should use only `header` for refresh page.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to escape ' in the url

```
 ob_start();
 header("Location: /localhost/site1");
 echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=\'/localhost/site1\'">'; //line 5
 die();

?>
```